# How does hibernate populate the entities

Tags: hibernate

very stupid question since I've been using hibernate for some time now but I was facing a special case and suddenly realised that I'm not sure how hibernate populates the DB entities.

```
public class User {
    ...
    @Column
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

When hibernate creates a new instance of User (when loading from the DB) how will it populate the property name of that instance? I always assumed hibernate would call setName for this but the case I'm having makes me suspect hibernate ignores the setter and (with reflection) sets the field's value directly?

thanks,
Stijn

Comment: There are no stupid questions.

Comment: No, but there are people that feel stupid for asking them :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate annotations and JPA use the placement of the Annotation to determine what kind of access to use. In the example you provided above, it would use field access.

from the [Hibernate Annotations documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/):

> Depending on whether you annotate fields or methods, the access type used by Hibernate will be field or property. The EJB3 spec requires that you declare annotations on the element type that will be accessed, i.e. the getter method if you use property access, the field if you use field access. Mixing annotations in both fields and methods should be avoided.

Comment: All 3 answers were very helpful. I moved the annotations to the getters and that fixed the issue I was facing. Also thanks to Vash and Mat.

Comment: Just one additional comment; it only worked once I moved all annotations to the getters and not simply that one that I needed.

Comment: In the end I moved all annotations back to the fields and added @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) to the one field where the getter/Setter needs to be used.

Answer (score 6):

> The access attribute allows you to
>   control how Hibernate accesses the
>   property at runtime. By default,
>   Hibernate will call the property
>   get/set pair. If you specify
>   access="field", Hibernate will bypass
>   the get/set pair and access the field
>   directly using reflection. You can
>   specify your own strategy for property
>   access by naming a class that
>   implements the interface
>   org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor.

```
access="field|property|ClassName"
```

[Source](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html)

Answer (score 1):

hibernate uses reflective property access by default
I suggest looking into system security policy (SecurityManager) if you want more details

Comment: You base on what that these that "Hibernate uses reflective property access by default" ?